# Switch between two different controls at runtime

Tags: wpf

I have a `ComboBox` with two values and a custom control as a part of menu. Is it possible to change this control to another (simple button) in the place of dispirited control at runtime if the `ComboBox` changes its value?

Are there any samples?

My idea is only to hide not needed controls by something like `Visibility` or `Height`/`Width` = 0.

Comment: As far I came cross, you need to hide not needed controls by Visibility = Collapse . If you make it hidden or Height/width = 0. It will take a space in UI.

Comment: Personally I would draw the control using a `<ContentControl>` and swap out the `ContentTemplate` property based on whatever your criteria is. This is easily done with a `Trigger` or can be done with code-behind too if you prefer

Answer (score 0):

The visibility of the ComboBox can typically be set at run time using a [BooleanToVisibilityConverter](https://github.com/joelmartinez/Khan-Academy-for-WinRT/blob/master/KhanAcademy/Common/BooleanToVisibilityConverter.cs).

For instance, let's say your Combo Box is bound to a list of products. When there are no products, you'd like to hide the Combo Box.

```
public class SampleViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged 
{
     public event EventHandler<PropertyChangedEventArgs> PropertyChanged;

     public IEnumerable<Product> Products { get; set; }

     public bool ShowProducts { get { return Products.Any(); } }
}
```

You can add a BooleanToVisibilityConverter to the Window's resources, and then bind to it.

```
<Window xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1">
  <Window.DataContext>
    <local:SampleViewModel />
  </Window.DataContext>
  <Window.Resources>
    <local:BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Name="BooleanToVisibilityConverter" />
  </Window.Resources>
  <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Products}"
            Visibility="{Binding ShowProducts, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}" />
</Window>
```